# Triggering a function by swiping through UICollectionView with single cell displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm currently making a Pokedex app and it's my first app.

Here is a screenshot of the view I'm working with. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVx13.jpg

Screenshot is taken mid swipe to show how I want to trigger UI updates.

The top bar with pictures of the Pokemon is a UICollectionView that displays a single UICollectionViewCell. I want trigger a function to update the UI to the next Pokemon when the pictures is halfway off the screen.

I have tried the following:

- func UICollectionView didEndDisplayingCell
- func UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath
- func UICollectionView willDisplayCell

The issue with these is that they trigger too late or too early.

I also tried using a content offset with scrollViewDidScroll:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let offset = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x

    var pokeID = Int((offset-width/2)/width+2) {
        didSet {
            print("Change Detected")
        }
    }
    print(offset)
    print(pokeID)
}
```

This code prints the correct Pokemon. I tried using willSet and didSet to trigger the change in the 'pokeID' but didn't have any luck.
Anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: You said “I tried using willSet and didSet” but you didn't say what property you put those observers on. Show us the code you tried.

Comment: I edited the code to show basically what I've tried. I did research the willSet didSet features, do I need to have the variables nested in a class or struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
private var currentPokeID: Int = -1 {
    didSet {
        if currentPokeID != oldValue {
            updateViews()
        }
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let bounds = self.collectionView.bounds
    let midpoint = CGPointMake(bounds.midX, bounds.midY)
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(midpoint) {
        currentPokeID = indexPath.item
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks so much for your help.